# Wordpress WP Geo Mashup, open link in new window?

Tags: wordpress

I am using the plugin WP Geo and have a 'mashup' map using the following shortcode:`[wpgeo_mashup height="550px" width="99%"]`.

This successfully places a marker on the map for each of my posts. When a marker is clicked it loads the relevant post but in the current window. How can I edit the plugin so it opens the post in a new tab/window? I'm assuming somewhere in the plugin I need a `target="blank"` but have no idea where....

Comment: Could you share the url of your site? To see the plugin in live and more easily find the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

Go to your **shortcode.php** file `(wp-geo/includes/shortcode.php)`.

And change the **69 line**:

```
$atts = wp_parse_args( $atts, array(
  'target' => '_self'
) );
```

For this:

```
$atts = wp_parse_args( $atts, array(
  'target' => '_blank'
) );
```